# How do you change the appearance of a button in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm very new to web development, so bear with me. I know how to do this when the submit button is created in the HTML page, with the help of CSS. But can you apply CSS to the javascript block? The reason I want to declare the Submit button in javascript is because eventually I want the submit button to send the choice into an SQL database, and I figure it would be much easier to do that in javascript as opposed to HTML. Please tell me if I'm completely on the wrong track.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myRadio");
  x.checked = true;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  <title>webpage</title>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
  </script>

</head>

<body>


  Radio Button:
  <input type="radio" id="myRadio">
  <input type="radio" id="myRadio2">
  <input type="radio" id="myRadio3">
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you use an HTML form, a submit button will automatically POST your data so you can then insert it to a database.  Here's a basic walkthrough: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data

Comment: I see. Also, what if I wanted to make a bunch of radio buttons. Is there some kind of 'for' loop in HTML? I feel like it's not a very powerful language.

Comment: There is no loop in HTML.  You could make your radio buttons in Javascript with a loop.  But for the submission of those radio inputs, I'd use the HTML form submit, unless you have requirements that go beyond the capabilities of the basic form submission.  There may be times where you need to interrupt that submission with JavaScript, or skip it altogether and submit using AJAX, but it sounds like the basic form submission should work for you.

Comment: HTML/HTML5 is a markup language, it does have lots of power just as every language has its own power. NO, it can not have conditional code lines, it is for displaying content on your web page. You need JavaScript for performing on radio buttons and PHP for storing their values. Both has the 'for' loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the basic idea of an HTML form, which will post the values of your selected radio buttons.  You can review the POST by looking at a dev tool like Firebug.

```
<body>
  <form method="POST" action="mypostpage.php">
    <input name="myRadio" type="radio" value="1"> Choice 1
    <input name="myRadio" type="radio" value="2"> Choice 2
    <input name="myRadio" type="radio" value="3"> Choice 3
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>
```

If you want to generate the radio buttons in JavaScript/JQuery, here's a general pattern:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/48x4510y/4/)

JQuery:

```
//see what value is selected
$('#myForm').on('change', function() {
   var selectedRadio =$('input[name="myRadio"]:checked', '#myForm').val()
   console.log(selectedRadio);
});

//add more radios
$('#addRadio').on('click', function() {
   var lastRadioVal = parseInt($('input[name="myRadio"]:last', '#myForm').val());
   for (i = lastRadioVal + 1; i <= lastRadioVal + 5; i++) {
      $('#myForm').append('<input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="' + i + '"> Choice ' + i );
   }
});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="myForm" method="POST" action="mypostpage.php">
   <input name="myRadio" type="radio" value="1"> Choice 1
   <input name="myRadio" type="radio" value="2"> Choice 2
   <input name="myRadio" type="radio" value="3"> Choice 3
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<input type="button" id="addRadio" value="Add Radio">
```

**UPDATED**

(JSFiddle link remains the same as above)

HTML

```
<form id="myForm" method="POST" action="mypostpage.php">
<input name="myRadio" type="radio" value="1"> Choice 1
<input name="myRadio" type="radio" value="2"> Choice 2
<input name="myRadio" type="radio" value="3"> Choice 3
<input id="myButton" type="button" value="Submit">
```

JQuery

```
//see what value is selected
$('#myForm').on('change', function() {
   var selectedRadio =$('input[name="myRadio"]:checked', '#myForm').val()
   console.log(selectedRadio);
});
//add more radios
$('#addRadio').on('click', function() {
   var lastRadioVal = parseInt($('input[name="myRadio"]:last', '#myForm').val());
   for (i = lastRadioVal + 1; i <= lastRadioVal + 5; i++) {
     $('#myForm').append('<input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="' + i + '"> Choice ' + i );
   }

  //change button style
  if($(this).hasClass("warning")) {
       $(this).removeClass("warning");
       $(this).addClass("error");
       $(this).val("Error!");
   } else {
      $(this).addClass("warning");
      $(this).val("Warning!");
   }
});
//change the button styling
$('#myButton').on('click', function() {
   $(this).addClass("validated"); 
   //you'll need to submit the form since the button is just a button and not a submit button.  i've commented it out below because this is just an example
   //$('#myForm').submit();
});
```

CSS

```
.validated {
  background: green;
}

.warning {
  background: yellow;
}

.error {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your response! I've implemented some of your code. But in regards with my original question, how do I change the looks/styling of the buttons? Also, I meant populating a single page with multiple radio buttons. Say I'm making a page with multiple radio buttons, with many questions without having to hard-code the questions over and over. Perhaps populate it from a database? A good example would be something like this. http://www.quizrocket.com/compatibility-test. Thanks!

Comment: My company's web blocker won't let me look at the example you posted, but I assume it's just a quiz with multiple choice options?  It's entirely possible to populate your form with data from a database (using something like PHP).  Or, if there's a small, basic set of "template" of radio buttons (perhaps, all "Yes" / "No"), or something of that sort, you could just use a constant variable and loop over it in code.  I'll update my example with how to change the styling of the button.

Comment: ok, i updated the JSFiddle with some examples of how to modify styling using JavaScript.  note:  i changed the button from type "submit" to type "button" so that i can avoid using preventDefault when the button is clicked.  for more info on how to populate data in a form from a database, you'll need to first decide what type of database you'll use (SQL, mySQL, etc), and what server side language you'll use (PHP, C#, etc).